# Ubuntu 18.04 Can't upgrade because of libpython3.6 version conflicts

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

After having updated to Ubuntu 18.04, when I try to upgrade my system via

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  gdb gir1.2-peas-1.0 libpeas-1.0-0 openshot
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

Of course I tried `sudo apt install -f` without success:

```
$ sudo apt install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

One suggested solution was to install each separately, but that doesn't work either:

```
$ sudo apt install libpeas-1.0-0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpeas-1.0-0 : Depends: libpython3.6 (>= 3.6.4~rc1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I tried to install libpython3.6, which doesn't work because

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   libpython3.6 : Depends: libpython3.6-stdlib (= 3.6.5-3) but 3.6.5-5~16.04.york1 is to be installed
```

Now I can't remove/install/downgrade to this version because apt would then remove about 200 packages including things like xorg, firefox, gnome-session and pretty much every package I ever heard of.

One other thing I wanted to try taken from the question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037528/apt-get-upgrade-error-for-python-packages-in-ubuntu-16-04) was

```
sudo dpkg --install --force all /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3[version].deb
```

but there was no file with my needed version number.

Edit: I downloaded the specific version via `apt download libpython3.6-stdlib=3.6.5-3` and installed it with above command. Now I can neither do upgrade nor autoremove, and I get this warning for both:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpython3.6-stdlib : Depends: libpython3.6-minimal (= 3.6.5-3) but 3.6.5-5~16.04.york1 is installed
 python3.6 : Depends: libpython3.6-stdlib (= 3.6.5-5~16.04.york1) but 3.6.5-3 is installed
```

What else can I do? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was caused by the `jonathonf/python-3.6` PPA I had enabled in 16.04. The upgrade to 18.04. disabled this PPA, installed the libpython3.6 in the non-ppa version (the york version are from the PPA), and therefore caused a missing dependency. First I had to revert the downgrade mentioned in the Edit with analogous apt download and forced dpkg commands.

I reenabled the PPA (also changed bionic to xenial in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jonathonf-ubuntu-python-3_6-xenial.list`) and after an easy

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -f && sudo apt upgrade
```

everything is working fine now again.

Comment: hi, Doopy, your answer was marked as the answer, but can you post the detail on how to enable the PPA? Thank you

Comment: @HaipengSu Sorry it's been a long time, I don't remember the details. I believe it should be either the standard `add-apt-repository` command or editing the sources file

Answer (score 15):

Looks like I got here by having installed python3.6 through the [deadsnakes](https://askubuntu.com/a/865569/294129) ppa in Ubuntu 16.  Then, after letting Ubuntu upgrade to 18 itself, it was in a conflicted state of depending on that `libpython` library presumably from the deadsnakes ppa but yet having a newer version of python that no longer knows about that dependency.

First, I had to remove the ppa the hard way by

```
sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa*
```

and then remove the conflicted library with

```
sudo apt remove libpython3.6-*
```

to remove both `libpython3.6-minimal` and `libpython3.6-stdlib`, which somehow didn't totally implode my system.

Doing a

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

installed python3.6 with some major caveats.

I had to [reinstall `ubuntu-desktop`](next time I logged in).  So probably better for you to run

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

before shutting down your computer!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem and this cmd helped me:
`sudo apt-get install gdb/bionic gir1.2-peas-1.0/bionic libpeas-1.0-0/bionic python3.6/bionic python3.6-minimal/bionic libpython3.6/bionic libpython3.6-minimal/bionic libpython3.6-stdlib/bionic`

Comment: That's the real answer here

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem:

the log(sorry for portuguese):

Os pacotes a seguir têm dependências desencontradas:

```
 libpython3.6 : Depende: libpython3.6-stdlib (= 3.6.15-1+focal3) mas 3.6.15-1+focal2 está para ser instalado
 libpython3.6-dev : Depende: libpython3.6-stdlib (= 3.6.15-1+focal3) mas 3.6.15-1+focal2 está para ser instalado
 libpython3.6-stdlib : Depende: libpython3.6-minimal (= 3.6.15-1+focal2) mas 3.6.15-1+focal3 está para ser instalado
 libpython3.7 : Depende: libpython3.7-stdlib (= 3.7.13-1+focal3) mas 3.7.13-1+focal1 está para ser instalado
 libpython3.7-dev : Depende: libpython3.7-stdlib (= 3.7.13-1+focal3) mas 3.7.13-1+focal1 está para ser instalado
 libpython3.7-stdlib : Depende: libpython3.7-minimal (= 3.7.13-1+focal1) mas 3.7.13-1+focal3 está para ser instalado
 python3.6 : Depende: libpython3.6-stdlib (= 3.6.15-1+focal3) mas 3.6.15-1+focal2 está para ser instalado
 python3.7 : Depende: libpython3.7-stdlib (= 3.7.13-1+focal3) mas 3.7.13-1+focal1 está para ser instalado
E: Dependências desencontradas. Tente 'apt --fix-broken install' sem nenhum pacote (ou especifique uma solução).
```

The log say that you shoud use "apt --fix-broken install" so I made it with the upgrade.

This solve it for me:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken upgrade
```