# Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 upgrade not working

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, 20.04

I wanted to upgrade my Ubuntu 16.04 to 20.04. As a part of the process I upgraded it first to 18.04. Then I tried all of the following methods but the upgrade didn't happen.

**Method 1**
[software updater](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dH0qe.png)

I tried clicking **Upgrade**, but nothing happened.
So I followed this tutorial https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/upgrade-ubuntu-18-04-to-20-04-lts-using-command-line/.

**Method 2**

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

I got the following error

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

**Method 3**

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

I got the following error

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Upgrades to the development release are only 
available from the latest supported release.
```

I have updated the packages in my machine multiple times, yet I keep getting these errors and cannot upgrade to 20.04. Can someone explain why this is happening and how to solve it. Please note that I'm currently using a x86_64 distribution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried doing the upgrade from an 18.04 stick?

Comment: Hey. Thanks. While upgrading I noticed that gdb gir1.2-peas-1.0 libpeas-1.0-0 qml-module-io-thp-pyotherside were not upgraded. So I followed https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061762/ubuntu-18-04-cant-upgrade-because-of-libpython3-6-version-conflicts and it worked. Thanks again :)